# How to remove rows from table in Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm brand new to Vue and have been struggling with this all day. I am trying to build a table using Vue components that can allow users to add and remove rows.

The problem I'm having is the `removeRow()` fuction is not removing the selected row, it's removing the last row off the table. Can anyone help me out?

```
Vue.component('newtemplate', {
    template: `<div>
                <div>
                    <button class="button btn-xs btn-success" @click="addRow">+</button>
                </div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-lg-6 nopadding"><input type="text" value="Col 1" class="borderless nopadding col-lg-6"></th>
                            <th class="col-lg-2 nopadding"><input type="text" value="Col 2" class="borderless nopadding col-lg-12"></th>
                            <th class="col-lg-2 nopadding"><input type="text" value="Col 3" class="borderless nopadding col-lg-12"></th>
                            <th class="col-lg-2 nopadding"><input type="text" value="Col 4" class="borderless nopadding col-lg-12"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :row="row">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control nopadding text-center">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control nopadding text-center">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control nopadding text-center">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control nopadding text-center">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button type="button" class="text-center button btn-xs btn-danger" v-on:click="removeRow(index)">-</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>`,
    data: function() {
        return {
            rows: [{row: ""}]
        }
    }, 
    methods:{
        addRow(){
            this.rows.push({row: ''});
        },
        removeRow: function(index) {
            this.rows.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
I made a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4d2uzx0r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue is removing the appropriate item from `rows`, but you don't have your inputs bound to anything, so Vue doesn't know about the values in the table row inputs, it only knows that it needs to render fewer rows. Vue takes shortcuts when it can and can only keep track of state that it knows about.

I've [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4d2uzx0r/5/) to bind the first column to a row element (each row item is now an array). If you fill in values in the first column, you can see that it deletes the appropriate row.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control nopadding text-center" v-model="row[0]">
```

and

```
addRow() {
    this.rows.push({
      row: []
    });
  },
  removeRow: function(index) {
    console.log("Removing", index);
    this.rows.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Roy. I didn't realise I was required to bind the values. I will work on doing that for all the cells now. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `key` attribute to your row element

```
<tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index" :row="row">
    //...
</tr>
```

Unique keys for  elements rendered with `v-for` loop helps vue's virtual dom to overcome rendering errors by identifying VNodes when diffing the new list of nodes against the old list.

See [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) for more info about `key` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately it hasn't solved the problem. The table is still deleting the last row, not the selected row.

Comment: @DylanHolloway Addinfg a dynamically bound key attribute should solve the problem ...can you produce a fiddle so that it can be debugged easily

Comment: @DylanHolloway here is your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4d2uzx0r/4/

Comment: Thanks Vamsi. Looks good. 

I'm finding now that the row is deleted when the button is pressed, but if you type some text in one of the inputs and then click delete, the text remains behind and just goes into the next row. Is there a way to fix that?